# PIL.UnidentifiedImageError PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file 'd:\\a/images/.pdf'

Tags: python, flask

```
from PIL import Image
import PyPDF2
tess.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Users\szaid\AppData\Local\Programs\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract'
translator=Translator()

project_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

app = Flask(__name__,
            static_url_path='',
            static_folder='static',
            template_folder='template')
photos = UploadSet('photos', IMAGES)
pdf = UploadSet('pdf', DOCUMENTS)
app.config['DEBUG'] = True
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']= 'images'

class Get(object):
        def __init__(self, file): enter code here
                if render_template('image.html'):
                        self.file = tess.image_to_string(Image.open(project_dir + '/images/'+ file))
                elif render_template('pdf.html'):
                        self.file = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(project_dir+'/pdff/'+ file)
```

And below, this is backend code to save the file in 'images' folder but its giving me an error.
I mean there is two different html pages and in both pages, there is an option to upload file and image. but dont know how to manage in flask...

```
@app.route('/pdf', methods=["GET","POST"])
def pdf():
        if request.method == 'POST':
                
                if 'pdf' not in request.files:
                        return 'there is no photo'
                name1 = request.form['pdf-name'] + '.pdf'
                pdf = request.files['pdf']
                path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], name1)
                pdf.save(path)
                TextObject = Get(name1)
                return TextObject.file

        return render_template('pdf.html')
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxxLq.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting this error because your path to the PDF file is wrong. You've added the file extension but the path is missing the file name. You also have a problem with your slashes in the path. A correct path would be like:

```
"D:\images\yourFileName.pdf"
```

Comment: hey thanks man, now I can save the file into that folder but the error is still the same.
I think there is problem in if else condition. Can you pls tell what can I put there instead of `if render_template('image.html'):
                        self.file = tess.image_to_string(Image.open(project_dir + '/images/'+ file))
                elif render_template('pdf.html'):
                        self.file = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(project_dir+'/images/'+ file)`

Comment: You don't have to read your image using Pillow to pass it to Tesseract. The path only is enough.

Comment: oh so I should I remove that `Image.open()` ? and it will be look like this right `tess.image_to_string(project_dir + '/images/'+ file)`

Comment: okay I got this. But there is one more error, its showing me **pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractError: (1, 'Error in pixReadStream: Pdf reading is not supported Error in pixRead: pix not read Error during processing.')**. I mean it is taking that first condition instead of second one. So what can I change in my code so that it will take that second condition.

Comment: It means it's always image.html. Unfortunately, I can't figure such a problem without running the code because it's related to your own files. But I believe it's good that you know not that you solved your first and second problems. I hope you find the reason soon.

Comment: okay I'll try to do something. Well thank you, you helped me alot!

Comment: You're always welcome! :)

Comment: hey! I solved the problem. I just created another class and done. Now its working properly.
btw How can I contact with you, coz there one more error and ik you'll solve that error.?

Comment: Feel free to post your problems on the platform. You'll always find awesome people assisting each other. I'm usually having a look to answer questions when I know the answer. ;)